# Call Google Cloud API from local Firebase Emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I've got a function which uses `@google-cloud/language`.

The function works when deployed live but when running in the local function emulator it complains

I've done `firebase login` with my Google account but get the following when running the function:

```
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud Natural Language API has not been used in project XXXXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/language.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXXXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

`XXXXX` is a project Id I don't recognise - where has this come from and how can I check if I'm mistaken?

The account I'm authed with `firebase` locally is already in the `Owner` role for the project, so either the project ID is wrong, or I need to grant permissions to the user?

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` for authentication:

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#windows

And restart all the things due to my ENV variable not being updated.